# Android Jenkins Build - debug "target" does not exist in the project error

Tags: android, ant, jenkins

I set up a Jenkins server along with the Android SDK on a headless Linux build server. I create an Android project via the typical "android create project ..." command.

After I "cd" into the new project, I can "ant clean debug" successfully as the jenkins user on the command line. I am running this from my Jenkins workspace directory (.jenkins/workspace/<project name>):

```
# su jenkins
$ ant clean debug
.... successful ....
```

However, when the Jenkins job builds I get a Target "debug" does not exist in the project "ProjectName" error

I set the sdk.dir variable to my Android SDK directory, so the command in the Jenkins log runs like:

```
$ ant -Dsdk.dir=/opt/java/android clean debug
```

I've set my permissions to 777 on the entire android SDK folder:

```
# chmod -R 777 /usr/java/android/android-sdk
```

I'm at a loss for what else I might be missing? Why would the command run on the command line but be unsuccessful as a Jenkins job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple days of frustration and wonder, it turns out that deleting the project and re-creating it with the EXACT same settings fixed the issue. In the mean time, I created and deleted several more jobs, and sometimes they have the error mentioned above, and sometimes they don't. Even with the exact same settings for the Job (letter for letter), it works at times and others it does not. I'm sorry I do not know how to fix this issue other than, delete the Job, recreate it, and try again!

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the command line ant build from the same place that jenkins is trying to?

Double check your

```
.jenkins/workspace/<project-name>
```

directory to make sure it has the same project files as where you're running things from the command line manually.

Comment: Yes, I should have stated that in the original question, I'll update it now. All of my commands were being run from .jenkins/workspace/<project name>...

Comment: do you have multiple build.xml files in the project?

Comment: no, it's just a standard android project created using the command line... I have the 2.8 plugin. I also noticed that when I add the "Create Android build files" build step, I immediately get a "
FATAL: String index out of range: -1 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" Exception and the build immediately exits with an exception. Is this an unstable version of the plugin?

Comment: Not sure. I don't use a plugin to build my Android projects. I just use Build->Add Build Step->Invoke Ant. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes that's the build step I use for building the ant project, just the standard "Invoke Ant" step... the "Create Android build files" is supposed to run "android update project" prior to invoking the ant build... it seems that the ant build isn't seeing the SDK folder and is unable to pull the debug dependency step from the android sdk folder...

Comment: Is ANDROID_HOME set to your sdk dir?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24079/discussion-between-purlogic-and-chuck-norris)

Comment: I posted a fix for this issue... it's pretty lame, but all of your points were very helpful! Thank you very much for your help with this!

Comment: @ChuckNorris Yeah, unfortunately the "Create Android build files" step is sometimes broken in the current release...

Comment: @ChuckNorris The Android Emulator Plugin has now been updated (version 2.8.1) to fix that issue with "Create Android build files".

Answer (score 0):

I also got same issue. However breaking my head for a while i was able fix the issue.
So if you want to run ant target on the command line, you have to use "ant target name"(e.g. ant debug). But to run same target by jenkin you should use only target name without ant(e.g. debug).

Not sure why it is so. But this resolved the issue for me.